# Raw Input Device RAWMOUSE Usage

Tags: c++, c, winapi, mingw

I'm using winapi's raw input devices for mouse input and it seems I'm not getting the correct values in my RAWMOUSE struct.

When I get the RAWMOUSE struct I get the values of **lLastX** and **lLastY** as I'd expect but for some reason the **ulRawButtons** is constantly 0. The msdn documentation says that ulRawButtons is *"The raw state of the mouse buttons"* so I take it this should change when I press a mouse button.

This is the code I create the raw input device with (I removed error checking for readability):

```
RAWINPUTDEVICE rid;
rid.usUsagePage = 0x01;
rid.usUsage     = 0x02;
rid.dwFlags     = RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
rid.hwndTarget  = myWindowHandle;
RegisterRawInputDevices(&rid, 1, sizeof(rid));
```

After the **WM_INPUT** message I call:

```
void handleRawInput(HWND window, UINT, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    RAWINPUT input;
    UINT szData = sizeof(input), szHeader = sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER);
    HRAWINPUT handle = reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(lParam);

    GetRawInputData(handle, RID_INPUT, &input, &szData, szHeader);
    if (input.header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
    {
        // Here input.data.mouse.ulRawButtons is 0 at all times.
    }
}
```

I'm using mingw32 (4.7) and I've defined **WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN**, **WINVER=0x0501** and **WIN32_WINNT=0x0501**.

Any ideas why I'm not getting the correct values for ulRawButtons?

Comment: That value comes straight from the device driver.  Maybe you got a quirky one that relies on Windows using the usButtonFlags.

Comment: The demo code from Microsoft MSDN web site on the topic "Using Raw Input" at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645546(v=vs.85).aspx provides example of both key board and mouse and as @Sean Cline mentions in his answer, my use of this demo code in a Win32 window app shows that `data.mouse.ulButtons` and `data.mouse.usButtonFlags` both change values as I click mouse pad buttons on my laptop however `data.mouse.ulRawButtons` seems to always be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows populates the [`RAWMOUSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct with what the mouse driver tells it via the [`MOUSE_INPUT_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct.

You'll notice that the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `MOUSE_INPUT_DATA` states the following:

> **RawButtons**
>
> > Specifies the raw state of the mouse buttons. The Win32 subsystem does not use this member.

What the MSDN page doesn't say is that not only does Win32 not use `RawButtons`/`ulRawButtons` but the mouse drivers it ships do not populate them. So, unless you have a mouse driver from a 3rd party vendor, you are never going to get this field set.

I think what you are looking to use is: `input.data.mouse.usButtonFlags` for mouse clicks and `input.data.mouse.usButtonData` for scroll wheel delta.

Comment: Thank you for your answere, I was under the impression that usButtonFlags showed the difference and the ulRawButtons showed the current state.